# Thoughts in the shower

Tags: halacha, torah-study, thought

What exactly should one think when taking a shower? Is Torah completely forbidden? Can I contemplate Gd or other religious matters? The shower is like the perfect place for alone time to think about Gd or your studies, so do any commentaries say this is allowed?

Comment: I hope you weren't thinking about this in the shower.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to [Shulchan Aruch OC 85:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.85.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> אפי' להרהר בד"ת אסור בבית הכסא ובבית המרחץ ובמקום הטנופת והוא המקום שיש בו צואה ומי רגלים: הגה ואפי' הלכות המרחץ אסור ללמוד במרחץ (ר"ן פ' כירה ונ"י בשם א"ח)
>
> Even to consider matters of Torah, is forbidden in the bathroom, and in the bathhouse, and in a filthy place - and this is in a place in which there is excrement or urine. Rema: and it is even forbidden to study the laws of the bathhouse in the bathhouse (Ran: Perek "Kirah" and Nimukei Yosef in the name of Orchos Chaim)

That being said, I saw [here](https://halachayomit.co.il/en/Default.aspx?HalachaID=1751&PageIndex=40) in the name of HaRav Ovadia Yosef that if there is no toilet/urinal in the room, thinking maybe okay:

> Summary: Regarding a room that houses a bathtub or shower nowadays, one may not recite any words of holiness in it. One is permitted, however, to think words of Torah in it and may therefore listen to a Torah lecture or holy songs from the radio and the like there.
>
> Note: Obviously, the aforementioned Halacha applies only to a room that houses a bathtub or shower alone; however, if there is a toilet in the room, one may not even think words of Torah there.

Comment: Is there anyone that says you can think about some sort of Torah? Also if you can’t think of Torah what do you think of according to them?

Comment: As I said, if there no toilet in the bathroom you can think of Torah.

Comment: @CuriousYid I think it was Rambam who wrote mathematics books when he was on the toilet

Comment: @MosesSupposes - it was the Vilna Gaon

Comment: @Dov I'm sure that I heard it about someone else as well - a friend of mine was working on translating them into English years ago, and I'm sure it wasn't the Vilna Gaon.

Comment: Some say he authored Cramer's Theorem